# Syntax error: “(” unexpected in bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

The script is for adding torrent files to a folder and having them added to transmission. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/me/box/*/*
do
dir=$(basename $(dirname "$file"));
sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/torrentwatch.log
sudo chmod -R 0777 /home/me/box/*/*
if "$file" = "/home/me/box/*/*.torrent"; then
echo [`date`] "$file" added to queue. >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
/usr/bin/transmission-remote localhost:9091 --auth=transmission:transmission -l -w /media/Media/Torrents/$dir -a "$file"
sleep 40 && rm "$file"
sleep 3 && sudo chmod -R 777 /media/Media && sudo chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /media/Media/info
fi
done
```

The problem is that when I run the script I get

```
/home/me/box/TV/Name.of.file.torrent: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've tried running the script with bash, sh, and zsh, and none seem to work. I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Try prepending `set -xv` to the script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25495636/1030675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues from what I see in your script.

Try the following.
Replace

```
dir=$(basename $(dirname "$file"));
```

With

```
dir=$(basename "$(dirname "$file")");
```

This should resolve your error, however, there are other few things I recommend:

```
echo [`date`] "$file" added to queue. >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
```

I would change that to

```
 echo "[$(date)]" "$file" added to queue. >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
```

This would prevent few issues, among them word splitting, and the somewhat dangerous and not portable use of `.

```
/usr/bin/transmission-remote localhost:9091 --auth=transmission:transmission -l -w /media/Media/Torrents/$dir -a "$file"
```

I would change that to:

```
/usr/bin/transmission-remote localhost:9091 --auth=transmission:transmission -l -w /media/Media/Torrents/"$dir" -a "$file"
```

This would prevent globbing and word splitting.